Relative homology of Klein bottle to figure-eight
I'm trying to compute the relative homology of the Klein bottle to $S^1\vee S^1$ as its 1-skeleton. Denoting these by $X$ and $A$, respectively, I have the homology groups
\[ H_2(X)=H_2(A)=0\]
\[H_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, \space H_1(A)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\]
\[H_0(X)=H_0(A)=\mathbb{Z}\]
and the chain groups
\[C_3(X)=C_3(A)=C_3(X,A)=0\]
\[C_2(X)=\mathbb{Z},\space C_2(A)=0,\space C_2(X,A)=\mathbb{Z}\]
\[C_1(X)=C_1(A)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z},\space C_1(X,A)=0\]
\[C_0(X)=C_0(A)=\mathbb{Z},\space C_0(X,A)=0\]
However, this implies that $H_2(X,A)=\mathbb{Z}/0=\mathbb{Z}$. Given that $H_2(X)=0$, how can the relative homology group be nonzero if the ordinary homology group is zero? Or am I missing something?

If $X=[0,1]$ and $A={0,1}$, then $H_1(X)=0$ while $H_1(X,A) \neq 0$: the homology $X$ can be zero while the relative homology is nonzero. The relative homology $H_n(X,A)$ may get contributions from $H_n(X)$ and $H_{n-1}(A)$.
